# Given an array A of size n, and integer k. Find maximum force by involving only k elements. Force of element is the square of its value

Tags: sorting, square

Sample Input:

4 4

1 2 3 4

Output:
30

Explanation:
Force = 1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 + 4*4 = 30

Sample Input:

2 1

1 10

Sample Output:
100

Can any one help me with more test cases. what can be more different inputs for this problem.

'''

```
 class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        long[] arr = new long[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            arr[i] = sc.nextLong();
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
 
               
        long sum = 0;
              
                 
        for (int i = N-1; k > 0; k--){
                        
            long squ = arr[i] * arr[i];
            sum  = sum + squ;
            i--;
        } 
                    
                System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

First convert all the negative value of an array to their positive value then apply the Arrays.sort() method and arrange the array in descending order.
Below is the code that you can write an check:-

```
class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n= in.nextInt();
        int k= in.nextInt();
        long[] arr = new long[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            arr[i]=in.nextLong();
        }
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(arr[i]<0){
                arr[i]=arr[i]*(-1);
            }
        }
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for(int i=0,j=n-1; i<j; i++,j--){
            long temp = arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[j];
            arr[j]=temp;
        }
        long ans=0;

        for(int i=0; i<k; i++){
            ans= ans+arr[i]*arr[i];
        }
        System.out.print(ans);
    }
}
```